# How to hide a textview and it's height according to condition in a collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview

I have a collectionView(rootView). Under that there are many views like userProfileView,ImageViews etc. The bottom two views are commentView and commentBoxView(It has one profile image, one `textView`, and one `imageView` of sent message). If the comments are blank in the json data then i want to hide the "commentView", and if there is data then i want to show the "commentView". The "commentBoxView" will be appear in both the condition.

For this purpose i made a outlet connection height of "commentView" and checked if the comment is blank then i wrote

```
commentViewHeight.constant = 0
commentView.isHidden = true
```

and if the comment is present

```
commentViewHeight.constant = 130
commentView.isHidden = false.
```

Now the problem is when the "commentView" is present it is coming fine. but when the comment is blank `textView` height of commentBoxView is getting increased .. i have checked the `constraint` twice, but unable to solve it. Please someone help me into this matter. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

If you use `UIStackView` to control UI layout, when one of sub-views become `hidden`, it will adjust UI layout automatically.

### Method 2

Google some `AutoLayout` tutorial in `WWDC` video. There is a technique, set 2 groups autolayout constriants on one UI component. For example, `group A` and `group B`constraints.

In `condition A`, set `group B` autolayout constraints `isActive` be false, and `group A`'s to true. 
In `condition B`, set `group A` autolayout constraints `isActive` be false, and `group B`'s to true.

I prefer above 2 tech. It make UI animation easy when switching UI status of the sub-views.

#### MORE

Sometimes, it needs to call `UIView`'s `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded` to refresh the frame of UIView and it's sub-views.

Comment: Thank you very much mam. i am going with method 2

Comment: madam tell me one thing how to adjust textview height, means if the data is less then how to handle the textview height?

Comment: You need to learn more about `intrinsicContentSize`. It can be integrated very well with auto layout. Let `intrinsicContentSize` decide the `height` property.

Comment: Okay Madam. Thank you